# catkin_make operation not permitted

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-hydro, devel, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently experienced a problem with catkin_make.  I am unsure what changed before I experienced the error as I had been using my computer for a couple of weeks without needing to use catkin_make, but I had been using the files in my catkin_ws in that two week period.  Therefore, I am uncertain what was the initial cause of the error (the error is included in the code segment below).

```
amanda@jade-shadow:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/amanda/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/amanda/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/amanda/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/amanda/catkin_ws/install" in "/home/amanda/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.86
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amanda/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py", line 29, in <module>
    os.chmod(output_filename, mode | stat.S_IXUSR)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/amanda/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/setup_cached.sh'
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python
  "/home/amanda/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:178 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Other than the very first time I ran catkin_make, I received the following error message, which looks very similar:

```
amanda@jade-shadow:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/amanda/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/amanda/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/amanda/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.86
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amanda/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py", line 29, in <module>
    os.chmod(output_filename, mode | stat.S_IXUSR)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/amanda/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/setup_cached.sh'
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python
  "/home/amanda/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:178 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I tried running `catkin_make clean` but I received the same error message as shown above.

I also went through my catkin_ws and made every package individually with `catkin_make_isolated`.  I moved the packages that did not successfully make into another folder on my computer.  However, the same error messages occurred when I ran `catkin_make` again.

I also made sure I ran:

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source devel/setup.bash
sudo apt-get update
rosdep update
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-control-msgs 
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-catkin
```

When no resolution was found, I ran

```
 rm -rf build
 rm -rf build build_isolated/
 rm -rf build/ build/
 rm -rf build/ devel devel_isolated/
```

and **the last command fixed my problem**.  However, I don't actually know what I did wrong.  I want to try to avoid doing it again.  I wanted to post this to help anyone experiencing the same problem and to ask for ideas of the cause of the problem. *I would appreciate any hints you could offer as to the possible cause of this issue.*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144766/catkin_make-operation-not-permitted/) by [Amanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3435/amanda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you copy your workspace e. g. as backup from an to a zip or from and to an NTFS file system? The unix "is executable" flags (chmod +x) does not survive all of these copies so afterwards when you restore your backup your sh and python script are not executable anymore, which might cause such errors....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3435/amanda/) on 2014-03-26**:
I didn't copy my workspace, but its possible that a package may have moved at some point. The files within those packages moved around, but I made sure the individual python files retained their chmod +x state.  Thanks for the lead - it sounds more reasonable than any hypothesis I've come up with.